# The Resurrection: early Jewish writings on it?

Tags: church-history, history, christian-literature

I'm currently studying the Resurrection, which I believe 100%. What ancient Jewish texts close to the first century speak about the Resurrection, or about the empty tomb that Christians claimed Christ rose from the dead from. what does the Talmud say about it?

Comment: Diego, the two questions linked above are extremely similar to this one.  One asks for writings (which you appear to be doing), and the other asks for evidence more generally.  If you can think of a way to differentiate this question from those, it could be reopened, but for the benefit of future readers we try to prevent answers from being spread across many different (but basically identical) questions.

Comment: I changed it a little bit

Comment: Questions about Jewish tradition aren't on-topic here, but are on-topic at [judaism.se].

Comment: The Ressurection of Christ is on topic here

Comment: Indeed, there is some crossover, but the people who know about ancient Jewish texts will be on the other site.

Comment: Well maybe I'll ask on there too, but I would like to hear from christan researchers instead.